# Error in bundle install in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundle

I installed bundle with rvm.
I went to my project in terminal, put code: bundle install and this error occurred:

```
~/Documentos/workspace/conselheiros$ bundle install
bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: interpretation invalid: File or Directory not found.
```

I had troubles in my installation? I was installing with rvm
I installed ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.0.8 and rubygems 1.8.24

Comment: can you show me the result of 'rvm list' and 'rvm gemset list' and 'ruby -v'?

Answer (score 0):

first make sure rvm is loading properly:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

it might be required to close terminal and open it again

you need to use rvm ruby:

```
rvm use 1.8.7 --install --default
```

and then you can continue:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: but i have this rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, what's echo $PATH? Oh, sorry, i don't say... i'm in ubuntu

Comment: run in your console `echo $PATH`

Comment: exactly, as you can see - the PATH is "broken", you need to `rvm use 1.8.7` to fix it, try running `rvm get stable` and make sure to read all the outputs - rvm tries to detect dangerous situations similar to this

Comment: when i used rvm get stable, in the final instalation say   * WARNING: You're using ~/.profile, make sure you load it,
    add the following line to ~/.bash_profile if it exists
    otherwise add it to ~/.bash_login:

      source ~/.profile